# Trouble creating Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

So I'm trying to have plans associated to the current user.
I have modal and migration called Plan. I have a method called user that I use the belongsTo() to get all the users that's associated to that plan. I'm not sure why its not working
Modal

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Plan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'stripe_plan',
        'cost',
        'description'
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePlansTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('stripe_plan');
            $table->float('cost');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('plans');
    }
}
```

I call the Plan model from my controller

[controller that calls the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmLX.png)

[the view that i call the users method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdxML.png)

It show blanks

[the output on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrKaZ.png)

Comment: Post code not images. nothing is shown because you have no user attached to the plans. Since you have no attribute `user_id` in the table `plans`. How are you supposed to know to wich user each plan belongs to ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't load the relationship. You can use the `with()` to achieve this.

```php
<?php 
// controller

class PlanController extends Controller {

    public function method(){
        $plans = Plan::with('user')->get(); 
        // Continue with Code
        // if you use compact to pass data to the view
        // else  $plans = Plan::all();
        // views('view_name', ['plans' => $plans] should word just fine
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont have to eager load a relation to be able to call up on it in blade. Calling the attribute `->user` in blades load the relation. `with()` is used for eager loading (load all users with only one DB query).

Comment: Thank you! that created the relationship. I also didnt have foreign key in my migration to point to the users id.

Comment: @N69S True. But when you pass info  via the `compact` statement, I don't think you can still access the DBQuery

Comment: Yes you have access, it is still a collection of Plan instances. compact doesnt convert it to array. Notice the syntax `$plan->user`. still an object